# Microsoft Security Essentials : Not complete at full scan

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

I'm using

- Microsoft Security Essentials(4.0.1526.0)
- Window 7 Professional(Service pack 1, 64bit)

When I run in full scan, it will always stop at this file *C:\Windows\system32\CodeIntegrity\driver.stl*

In the previous version *(I'm not sure which version)* it's has the same problem.

NOTE : In previous version can fix the problem by setting CPU limit to 30%. But at this version (4.0.1526.0) it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: How long did you leave it on that file before you cancelled the scan?

Comment: @Dracs About an hour. NOTE : while scaning it will show the time that how much the program does. In this case, the time stop running too.

Comment: Are there any other AV's running ? Check this out http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanning/mse-scan-freeze-on/96fd9766-22d3-49a7-a06f-ce3597010035

Comment: Open a forum support case with Microsoft if answers or suggestions here do not help...https://support.microsoftsecurityessentials.com/Default.aspx?&scrx=1

Comment: Also it will be worth to check your HardDisk health and run a `chkdsk /f`.

Answer (score 1):

First run a System File checker

Open an elevated command prompt and run the is command

> sfc /scannow

if will scan and replace any corrupted system files. Then try the MSE scan again.

If that fails to solve it [Run a offline chkdsk on the C drive](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6565)

Boot from a W7 install or [System Repair](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02058933&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en) Disc, load Win RE (repair your computer), then choose command prompt and run this command

> chkdsk /r C:

If it is a large hard drive it will take quite some time to complete, do Not interrupt the disk check.

Note: some PC's have the Windows Recovery Environment on the hard drive and can be accessed by using F8 at the bios splash screen, then choose "repair your computer" from the advanced menu.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Moab. I found this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/w7itprogeneral/thread/18402c88-5ce0-41c9-ac24-b83d46a85ecf) but can't solve my problem.Is it different from your answer? If it is, I will try soon. Thank you so much.